# How to kill/interrupt all tcp connections using console?

Tags: networking

Is it possible to disrupt all tcp activity with a push of a button instead of hunting down individual ones? And I mean only kill the connections themselves (established, syn, wait, etc -- just make'em disappear), not killing the process that is making those connections (it's ok if it exits on it's own), and not restarting any network components

Comment: You can bring down the network interface - that will disrupt *all* connections, not only TCP ones. And, strictly speaking, and does not "restart" any "network components" (like a DHCP client). If you bring the interface up again, and make sure you get (or set) the same IP, connections that are not timed out will even resume. But not sure if that is the solution you had in mind...

Comment: Thanks, this is the quickest "push-a-button" way that worked for me. Write it as an answer, and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bring down the network interface - that will disrupt all connections, not only TCP ones. And, strictly speaking, and does not "restart" any "network components" (like a DHCP client).

If you bring the interface up again, and make sure you get (or set) the same IP, connections that are not timed out will even resume.

Comment: Bringing it down will not disrupt connections unless/until they have traffic flowing and/or the server follows the state of the interface. And yes, it could trigger other actions for any process listening to netlink events.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `iptables` rule. Something like this:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m --cstate ESTABLISHED -j REJECT
```

Or `tcpkill` (part of package `dsniff`)

```
$ sudo tcpkill -i INTERFACE -9 TCPDUMP_FILTER
```

Note that in both situations, you will need to have traffic before they kick in. If you have an `ssh` session running and you run something like:

```
$ sudo tcpkill -i INTERFACE -9 port 22
```

In both cases the connection will actually be killed only if there is incoming/outgoing traffic (even a keepalive packet will do). Otherwise they will be just interrupted (no more traffic will flow through them).

If you are using IPv6, with `tcpkill` you will need to interrupt those too.

**Notes about removing/adding the interface**

Removing the interface and recreating it with the same IP is NOT a solution, because it could end up doing nothing at all. You can check that with this simple setup:

```
$ sudo ip tuntap add mode tun example
$ sudo ip address add 192.0.2.1 dev example
```

Now, on two terminals, create a server:

```
(terminal-1) $ nc -l -s 192.0.2.1 -p 9999
```

and a client:

```
(terminal-2) $ nc 192.0.2.1 9999
```

Write a bit on either side (client/server) and see it working.

Now remove the interface:

```
$ sudo ip link del example
```

Write some more on both sides (you will notice the data doesn't flow), then wait, two minutes for example, and recreate the link:

```
$ sleep 120
$ sudo ip tuntap add mode tun example
$ sudo ip address add 192.0.2.1 dev example
```

Type something. Or wait some more and you will see your conection resume, no data lost.

Depending on your server/client (they could be listening to interface events and drop the connection by themselves) the result of removing/recreating the interface could be, at least:

- nothing
- clean exit
- unclean exit

Comment: Removing the interface will not kill the program, rather the program will commit suicide. As I said in the question, if the process exits on it's own then that's fine by me. I didn't want to kill anything directly not because I worry about the program, but because I'm too lazy to hunt down the processes.

Comment: And "commit suicide" means?